# Auto date added to adjacent cells when data is entered

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, date

I am trying to create a spreadsheet to track student loan outs that will automatically put the date in an adjacent cell.  The spreadsheet would be set up like this:

- Column 1 would be "name"
- Column 2 would be a drop down of what was loaned out
- Column 3 would be the date
- Column 4 would be a drop down menu again
- Column 5 would be the date
- Column 6 would be the drop down menu again
- Column 7 would be the date

I Would like it to work so that each time i select something from the drop down menus, the current date would automatically be fill the adjacent cell so that I can track what was loaned out and the date each loan out was given.  I am not sure if this is possible. I saw a script from OnenOnlyWalter that would add the date to column 2 and I tried to modify it so that it would work for multiple columns but no such luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to add the dates:

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  if(col == 2 || col == 4 || col == 6) {
    var adjacentCell = aCell.offset(0, 1);  
    var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss");
    adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
  }
}
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Adjacent Cell](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdENlQVh5X04zT0JfRzR6a01DeXpWVkE&usp=sharing)**
Add the code to the script editor (*Tools > Script editor...*), press the save button and you're on the go !!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  It worked perfectly. I got an error message but it worked. I adjusted the script so it puts the dates in the columns I needed.  Thanks for writing the script and putting me in the right direction.